mysqldump: Couldn't find table ">"
Can anyone help with the following mysqldump command:
i am trying to dump a specific schema, but mysqldump keeps expecting me to specify a table. Or more specifically i keep getting the following:

mysqldump: Couldn't find table: ">"

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\mysql-8.0.37-winx64\bin\mysqldump.exe" -h "mydbname.mysql.database.azure.com" -u "myDBUser" --password="-#$passwordWithSpecialCharacters$#-" --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false schemaName > "C:\Users\My User Name\Desktop\Dump_2024-08-26 14_45_42.sql"

Thanks!

The error indicates that mysqldump is misinterpreting the >  as part of the command rather than as a redirection operator. I am not sure if it is because of special characters on the password file. I suggest create a test.cnf with which will contain the username, password and host something like [client] user=myDBUser password=-#$passwordWithSpecialCharacters$#- host=mydbname.mysql.database.azure.com . The command would be "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\mysql-8.0.37-winx64\bin\mysqldump.exe" --defaults-file="C:\Users\YourUserName\.test.cnf" --single-transaction ....

When you write schemaName in your command, do you mean the database_name or the user_schema? In MySQL schema_name is the equivalent of the name of the database you want to export or the database_schema, not the user_schema.
